ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest
I've received this message : "ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest - Your app includes “Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts”...., . I've created a PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy with infos from generator manifest, but I've the same error. In my application there is no personal e-mail address, phone or personal data
What can I do to solve my problem
Thank you very much
Best regards
Georges
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>CA92.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>


How did you addded it? Which version of Charts are you using? Last version should be compliant: https://github.com/ChartsOrg/Charts/blob/master/Package.swift

I' ve only create a new file PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in my application. Where I can see the version of Charts? Thank you

I've looked at gitub and install the last Charts with pod install. I think I ve to create a new archive?

Now I've an error : 'ChartDataSet' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection' when I try to create the archive

I've tried to I install DGCharts with Package dependencies but know I've an error

No such module 'DGCharts' is the error

I've installed framework for DGCharts. Now the compile is ok. I submit for Appstore. I've not the  ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest for the moment. Thank you very much Larme
